# GAS ORM many-many relation with attributes

Tags: codeigniter, orm

I'm using CodeIgniter and I'm starting to work with gas orm.

One of my **m-n-relationship-tables** using a **composite key** has also some **additional attributes** to the releation.

For Example:
Table teams, Table employees, and a m-n table which binds them together + adding the attribute role

**Is it possible to get the attribute using GAS ORM?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Simply create a new relationship in one of the two tables you are going to link with the pivot table that refers to the pivot table itself as a has_many relation. (But dont do the linking stuff in the model file, eg:

```
ORM::has_many('\\Model\\User\\Role')
```

instead of

```
ORM::has_many('\\Model\\User\\Role => \\Model\\Role')
```

See http://ellislab.com/forums/viewreply/1050559/ for exact the same question.